# Что прочитать, чтобы хорошо понимать как в linux взаимодействуют разные элементы среды разработки?

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, веб-сервер, wsl, wsl2

Неопытный программист, столкнулся с тем, что после установки на WSL 2, сборки из apache, mysql и всего, что нужно оказалось:

1. версию php нужно устанавливать отдельно на сервере и отдельно в
   пакет с самим php, иначе у виртуального хоста может быть другая
   версия php, чем в целом на сервере;
2. постоянно рекурсивно вынужден
   проставлять права на папки, потому что не понимаю систему прав на папки
   (причем 5-6 статей уже прочитал по этому поводу).
3. Дополнительно к php, нужно кучу пакетов устанавливать непонятно назначения, в любом руководстве по настройке локального сервера на WSL свой набор. Как понимать, что устанавливаешь? Сейчас у меня все работает только потому, что инструкция правильная, а понимать - не понимаю.

Опытные специалисты, направьте, пожалуйста! Документация по частным вопросам читаю, что Apache, что Mysql и других составляющих, но что-то ясности не наступает..

Что прочитать концентрированное, чтобы понять всю эту систему, как она взаимодействовать, что ставить, что нет?

Comment: Ну ты затрагиваешь область devops. Там дофига всего. Но я бы для начала советовал отказаться от прослойки WSL, потому что, имхо, ненужная абстракция, которая мне немного принесла боли из-за своей "тесной интеграции". Или переходи на Linux или работай через virtualbox с сетевым мостом.